# TensorFlow 1.14.0 is not using GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I set up TensorFlow using `pip install --user tensorflow-gpu` on my Ubuntu 19.04 laptop. All dependencies like CUDA, CUDNN are installed to and working. But still, when importing TensorFlow and checking `tf.test.is_gpu_available()` gives me False. I have tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling TensorFlow, which did not work.
Output of `tf.test.is_gpu_available()`:

> 2019-06-27 14:06:18.359739: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports
>   instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
>   FMA 2019-06-27 14:06:18.611194: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency:
>   2194885000 Hz 2019-06-27 14:06:18.621295: I
>   tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x19d54e0
>   executing computations on platform Host. Devices: 2019-06-27
>   14:06:18.621339: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]
>   StreamExecutor device (0): ,  2019-06-27
>   14:06:18.742193: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42]
>   Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1 2019-06-27
>   14:06:18.869601: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful
>   NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be
>   at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero 2019-06-27
>   14:06:18.870469: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0
>   with properties:  name: GeForce 920M major: 3 minor: 5
>   memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.954 pciBusID: 0000:08:00.0 2019-06-27
>   14:06:18.870675: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcudart.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64 2019-06-27
>   14:06:18.870812: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcublas.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64 2019-06-27
>   14:06:18.870973: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcufft.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64 2019-06-27
>   14:06:18.871111: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcurand.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64 2019-06-27
>   14:06:18.871228: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcusolver.so.10.0'; dlerror:
>   libcusolver.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
>   2019-06-27 14:06:18.871352: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcusparse.so.10.0'; dlerror:
>   libcusparse.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
>   2019-06-27 14:06:20.233321: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42]
>   Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7 2019-06-27
>   14:06:20.233363: W
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1663] Cannot dlopen
>   some GPU libraries. Skipping registering GPU devices... 2019-06-27
>   14:06:20.407248: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device
>   interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix: 2019-06-27
>   14:06:20.407318: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 
>   2019-06-27 14:06:20.407351: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N 
>   2019-06-27 14:06:20.441266: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful
>   NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be
>   at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero 2019-06-27
>   14:06:20.443613: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA
>   service 0x4ed6d40 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
>   2019-06-27 14:06:20.443670: I
>   tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor
>   device (0): GeForce 920M, Compute Capability 3.5 False

Output of deviceQuery from CUDA Samples:

> CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)
>
> Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)
>
> Device 0: "GeForce 920M"   CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version
>   10.1 / 10.1   CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    3.5   Total amount of global memory:                 4046 MBytes (4242341888
>   bytes)   ( 2) Multiprocessors, (192) CUDA Cores/MP:     384 CUDA Cores
>   GPU Max Clock rate:                            954 MHz (0.95 GHz)
>   Memory Clock rate:                             900 Mhz   Memory Bus
>   Width:                              64-bit   L2 Cache Size:
>   524288 bytes   Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)
>   1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)   Maximum Layered
>   1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers   Maximum
>   Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers 
>   Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes   Total
>   amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes   Total number of
>   registers available per block: 65536   Warp size:
>   32   Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048   Maximum
>   number of threads per block:           1024   Max dimension size of a
>   thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)   Max dimension size of a grid
>   size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)   Maximum memory pitch:
>   2147483647 bytes   Texture alignment:                             512
>   bytes   Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy
>   engine(s)   Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
>   Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No   Support host
>   page-locked memory mapping:       Yes   Alignment requirement for
>   Surfaces:            Yes   Device has ECC support:
>   Disabled   Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes   Device
>   supports Compute Preemption:            No   Supports Cooperative
>   Kernel Launch:            No   Supports MultiDevice Co-op Kernel
>   Launch:      No   Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 8
>   / 0   Compute Mode:
>        < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >
>
> deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 10.1, CUDA
>   Runtime Version = 10.1, NumDevs = 1 Result = PASS

Comment: Looking at the tensorflow errors, it seems like it is trying to load CUDA 10.0 runtime libraries, but you have CUDA 10.1 installed.

Comment: @sgarizvi it was exactly the problem. However, I could not CUDA 10.0 working on Ubuntu 19.04, so I installed 18.04 and everything worked

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My particular problem was that **TensorFlow 1.14.0** were seeking for **CUDA 10.0** binary, while I had only **10.1** installed. For some reason CUDA 10.0 could not be installed on my **Ubuntu 19.04** so I installed **18.04** instead and followed standard way to make **TF** work with GPU (install **CUDA 10.0**, install **CUDNN**, etc.) and everything works just fine.

This table shows TF versions vs. required CUDA versions: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#linux

Here are instructions from TF:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#ubuntu_1804_cuda_10

You may also downgrade to TF 1.12 (CUDA 9.0): https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#ubuntu_1604_cuda_90_for_tensorflow_1130

Comment: Here is how to install Cuda10.0 https://gist.github.com/Mahedi-61/2a2f1579d4271717d421065168ce6a73#file-cuda_10-0_installation_on_ubuntu_18-04

Answer (score 3):

`conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu=1.14.0` seems install tensorflow 1.14.0 that supports CUDA 10.1.

More details can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26289#issuecomment-515494697).

Answer (score 2):

make sure your `cuda` version is matched with TensorFlow, more details could be found [here](https://tensorflow.google.cn/install/source)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to build it using Bazel or MYSYS. The tensorflow website suggests how to do this.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows

Once the prerequisites are installed, clone tensorflow from github.

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
cd tensorflow
```

Configure the system build

```
python ./configure.py
bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda --define=no_tensorflow_py_deps=true //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
--define=no_tensorflow_py_deps=true
```

Then build and install

```
bazel-bin\tensorflow\tools\pip_package\build_pip_package C:/tmp/tensorflow_pkg
pip3 install C:/tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-version-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```