# Keras (tensorflow) finds GPU, but only runs on cpu w/ Cuda 10.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Already many questions are posted about this, but none of them really answers mine or there is a small difference with what I came across.

I'm on ubuntu 18.04 and installed keras following the default instructions with CUDA 10.1 AND tensorflow-gpu.

When running something tensorflow detects I have a GPU, but when I'm checking cpu vs gpu usage, he still only seem to run on cpu. I came across [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/41958) thread and run that script. It confirms what I was guessing, that he can't use my gpu for some reason:

```
2019-09-19 21:05:57.730197: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2019-09-19 21:05:57.730247: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1663] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Skipping registering GPU devices...
2019-09-19 21:05:57.730281: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-09-19 21:05:57.730303: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 
2019-09-19 21:05:57.730317: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N 
2019-09-19 21:05:57.922335: W tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1412] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
```

When listing the devices it says:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 57580461479478464
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 6376288845656491190
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 17409275481256463364
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
]
```

But halfway the logs, tensorflow outputs this:

```
2019-09-19 20:44:32.676537: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 860M major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.0195
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
```

./deviceQuery outputs this:

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 860M"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          10.1 / 10.1
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    5.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 2004 MBytes (2101870592 bytes)
  ( 5) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     640 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1020 MHz (1.02 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             2505 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              128-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 2097152 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device supports Compute Preemption:            No
  Supports Cooperative Kernel Launch:            No
  Supports MultiDevice Co-op Kernel Launch:      No
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 10.1, CUDA Runtime Version = 10.1, NumDevs = 1
Result = PASS
```

Anyone knows why tensorflow can't find my GPU or how to make it available?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it's because of cuda 10.1. Follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56803006/9637085)

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's not running on the GPU? Depending on the model, it's easily possible that the GPU usage would never go above, say, 10%.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I'm not 100% certain, but when I watch nvidia-smi, python3 does appear in the list at the bottom, but with max 24mb memory and almost no usage, while my cpu usage in top goes to 700% so I'm guessing not?

Comment: @Hamed it was indeed because of the wrong cuda version! Feel free to add an answer and I'll upvote & mark as solution ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of cuda 10.1. You need to downgrade to cuda 10.0.

Here's a similar [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56803006/9637085).