# Debug broken Tensorflow-gpu installation with Conda (1.14 vs 2.3), Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tensorflow, conda

I just recently made the mistake of fiddling with my TF install, and broke everything. I used to have two Conda envs with respectively TF 1.14 and 2.1, Cuda 10.1, both working fine. After much plumbing, I now have my main Conda env with TF 2.3, Cuda 10.1, but after doing everything to install the libs & tensorrt, and creating the new env for TF 1.14 (still some older code I haven't ported), what used to work like a charm, the `conda install -c (conda-forge|anaconda) tensorflow-gpu` now fails to see my gpu.

```
Sun Nov  1 09:15:15 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.36.06    Driver Version: 450.36.06    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 166...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   38C    P8     6W /  N/A |     11MiB /  5944MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1469      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2719      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

```
/usr/local/cuda:
bin  doc  extras  include  lib64  libnsight  libnvvp  LICENSE  nsightee_plugins  nvml  nvvm  README  samples  share  src  targets  tools  version.txt

/usr/local/cuda-10.1:
bin  doc  extras  include  lib64  libnsight  libnvvp  LICENSE  nsightee_plugins  nvml  nvvm  README  samples  share  src  targets  tools  version.txt

/usr/local/cuda-10.2:
doc  lib64  LICENSE  README  targets  version.txt

/usr/local/cuda-11.1:
include  lib64  src  targets
```

And lastly the error:

```
In [2]: tf.test.is_gpu_available()                                                                                                                                                     
2020-11-01 00:42:23.536860: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX 
AVX2 FMA                                                                                                                                                                               
2020-11-01 00:42:23.570537: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2295750000 Hz                                                                     
2020-11-01 00:42:23.571572: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x557fe1bd9660 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:                             
2020-11-01 00:42:23.571626: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>                                                    
Out[2]: False
```

(Whereas in my other env with TF 2.3 everything is fine:)

```
In [2]: tf.config.list_physical_devices()                                                                                                                                              
2020-11-01 09:11:18.858155: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1                                           
2020-11-01 09:11:18.901461: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NU
MA node, so returning NUMA node zero                                                                                                                                                   
2020-11-01 09:11:18.901901: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties:                                                                   
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti with Max-Q Design computeCapability: 7.5                                                                                              
coreClock: 1.335GHz coreCount: 24 deviceMemorySize: 5.80GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 268.26GiB/s                                                                                         
2020-11-01 09:11:18.901934: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1                                      
2020-11-01 09:11:18.903297: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10                                        
2020-11-01 09:11:18.904777: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10                                         
2020-11-01 09:11:18.905133: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10                                        
2020-11-01 09:11:18.906631: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10                                      
2020-11-01 09:11:18.907411: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10                                      
2020-11-01 09:11:18.910462: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7                                          
2020-11-01 09:11:18.910683: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NU
MA node, so returning NUMA node zero                                                                                                                                                   
2020-11-01 09:11:18.911185: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NU
MA node, so returning NUMA node zero                                                                                                                                                   
2020-11-01 09:11:18.911554: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0                                                                     
Out[2]:                                                                                                                                                                                
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'),                                                                                                                     
 PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_CPU:0', device_type='XLA_CPU'),                                                                                                             
 PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_GPU:0', device_type='XLA_GPU'),                                                                                                             
 PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

I also know that the Conda-distributed version of [TF worked with Cuda 10.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58622879/9638108), it was working on my machine until yesterday, and now that I redo what seems to me the same steps, nothing works, so what could be the issue...?

Has anyone encountered this? I also need to solve this on another machine, exact same problem, and no `cuda-11.1` in `/usr/local` this ... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after much wrangling (and it is certainly a symptom of madness of wanting to setup not one but two versions of TF on one machine in this day and age), the solution I found to work was:

- in the main, TF 2.3 environment, follow the steps described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu), except for two tweaks:

  - DO NOT INSTALL TENSORFLOW YET.
  - currently (October 2020) `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends cuda-10-1` does not work any longer, but `conda install cudatoolkit=10.1.243` does, see [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36121#issuecomment-583922515);
  - **OTHER CAVEAT** I also notice that TF 2.3 could not find the whole array of libraries (libcublas.so.10, libcufft.so.10, libcurand.so.10, etc.) until I installed cuda 10.2... `conda install cudatoolkit=10.2.89`, which I've seen people talk about [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34759#issuecomment-633819017), so unclear that this is the perfect solution (other people symlink the files, or copy them manually from one dir to another, those hellish days will be remembered;
  - (another option, without TensorRT, but very useful for purging cuda and nvidia things, and fail-safe, can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43236#issuecomment-693244342))
- after all the libraries, cuda, etc., are installed (you need a reboot at this point, and you can check that your gpu(s) are visible using `nvidia-smi`, create a fresh environment, and install TF 1.4 using the *anaconda* channel (conda-forge failed for me): `conda install tensorflow-gpu=1.14`.
- finally, at the very end, go back to the main env and install tensorflow with pip.

In there, you should have this:

```
$ conda list | grep tensop tensor
tensorboard               1.14.0           py37hf484d3e_0    anaconda
tensorflow                1.14.0          gpu_py37h74c33d7_0    anaconda
tensorflow-base           1.14.0          gpu_py37he45bfe2_0    anaconda
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0                     py_0    anaconda
tensorflow-gpu            1.14.0               h0d30ee6_0    anaconda
```

And, importantly:

```
$ pip freeze | grep tensor
tensorboard==1.14.0
tensorflow==1.14.0
tensorflow-estimator==1.14.0
```

This does not work if you installed TF with pip beforehand.

After that, activate your other base env, and complete your installation with pip

```
$ pip install tensorflow
```

Which should give you:

```
$ conda list | grep tenso tensor
tensorboard               2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

And:

```
$ pip freeze | grep tensor
tensorboard==2.3.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.7.0
tensorflow==2.3.1
tensorflow-estimator==2.3.0
```